# Worldpay Javascript Hosted Payment Page in lightbox/iframe does not work

Tags: payment, hosted

I am trying to use https://payments.worldpay.com/ngpp/integration/wpg/corporate?OrderKey=YOUR_ORDER_KEY&Ticket=YOUR_TICKET_ID .  I always get the error
Application is not available
The application is currently not serving requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is still starting.
Not understanding what is the issue with this url.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that URL is either incorrect, or could be a product they have sunset at some point.
I’m not sure which API you are trying to connect to, but here is the link to WorldPay’s documentation https://developer.worldpay.com/docs
If you are looking for alternative payment providers, we integrated with USIO (https://payments.usiopay.com/2.0/documentation/) which is a registered payment facilitator.
They have connections into TSYS and WorldPay and we found their API’s are much easer to use than connecting directly.